# Firestore security rules: regex on key

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Do firestore security rules support regex on the field name? So instead of the value of `username`...

```
username.matches(REGEX)
```

...the key `username` itself:

```
request.resource.data.keys().matches(REGEX)

// or...
 
request.resource.data.matches(REGEX)
```

I've tried finding this answer in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

`request.resource.data.keys()` is an array of keys and you cannot loop over list items in security rules. The best you can do is check for every key and then check if it matches the regex.

```
allow write: if request.resource.data.keys()[0].matches('REGEX')
```

You would have write same statement for all list items ([1], [2]...) and it's still difficult to guess how many keys that object has.